# Example of a nowhere-zero 4-flow

Tags: graph-theory

I'm trying to understand the concept of nowhere-zero-flows.

I have this [example graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBIoR.png) that's supposed to have a nowhere-zero-4-flow (since it has a Hamiltonian cycle).

So by one of the theorems by Tutte, it should also have a nowhere-zero $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$-flow.

If I understood it correctly, the flows assigned to the edges need to have a value out of $\{(0,1), (1,0), (1,1)\}$ and have to sum up to an even number.

For some reason I don't manage to assign the flows correctly. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is the linked graph supposed to be directed?

Comment: i'm trying to find an orientation for the graph such that it has a nowhere-zero-4-flow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take an entirely clockwise orientation; label all edges outside the triangle $(1,1)$, and label the edges of the triangle $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ accordingly.

[image]

There are of course many variations on this solution.

Comment: oh - i understand what i did wrong all the time now!!!
thanks a lot!!

Comment: You're welcome, I've added a picture for clarity.

Comment: the direction can also be removed because it is in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ can't it?

Comment: is there a way to use the Hamiltonian cycle to construct the nowherezero-$\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$-flow?

Comment: Indeed the direction can be removed, because the group has exponent $2$, i.e. $2g=0$ for all $g\in G$, or equivalently $g=-g$ for all $g\in G$.

Comment: If a connected graph $G$ has a Hamiltonian cycle, then it is a union of graphs that are cycles (here the hexagon and the triangle). Each of these has precisely three nowhere zero $\Bbb{Z}_2\times\Bbb{Z}_2$-flows, the three constant flows. Summing these flows yields a $\Bbb{Z}_2\times\Bbb{Z}_2$-flow, and if they are distinct we get a nowhere zero flow. It isn't hard to prove that this always works, but this comment box is too small, it's a nice exercise.

Comment: thanks a lot again!